# Auto date change in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way to change two dates when increasing another number field.

I invoice a Friday and Saturday shift weekly and adjust the invoice number by 1 (33 to 34 etc)

How Can I get the date to change on the invoice when I increase invoice number.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula? Like `=DATE(2016,1,1)+(A1*7)`, assuming that invoice 1 is from 1/1/2016 and your invoice number is in field A1? Or is it more complicated than this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a **base date** and a **base invoice number**.  Say the date is 8/20/2006 and the number is 100 and the number is stored in **A1**.  The date formula would be:

```
=(A1-100)+DATE(2006,8,20)
```

each time the invoice number is increased, the date increases by one day.